# forcing a file to open in predefined application in iOS

Tags: ios, file

I am trying a simple web app which downloads files from internet and saves on iPad. Theses  files are of .pdf,.xls,.doc, etc format. Now, I want to assign a default application to open a specific file type. (Say Adode reader for pdf file, Some image viewer app for image files etc). I dont want my app/os to decide which app the file should open in. Instead, if assigned app doesnt exists then it should give me a message that no such app found. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Simply, no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a web app you cannot do such things.

If you go native, you can use Custom URL Schemes (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

But with Custom URL Schemes, you only are able to pass a view parameters. If you want more, UIPasteboard is recommended.

Apps are sandboxed. You cannot access other apps, nor their data!!!
But on native apps you can pass over data with pasteboard, call a custom url handler, pass a few parameters to cause the other apps to process your data.

**Often App developers, like camera+ offer a documentation for the usage of their custom url schemes ([Camera+ URL Schemes API](http://api.camerapl.us/app-api))**